# Powershell : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: powershell, servicenow

When I try to connect with ServiceNow via powershell I am getting "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized". If I encrypt the password, I am getting "Keyset does not exist".

```
$TenantCredential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $TenantAdmin, (ConvertTo-SecureString -a -f (Unprotect-CmsMessage -IncludeContext –To "*svc.accountman@olive.com*" -Content $TenantAdminCredential))
```

Comment: Is it indicates, you're not authorized, meaning you credentials are likely incorrect. If the `$TenantCredential` contains a local account on the remote server, try to add the computer name (or just a dot): `.\myAdminName`.

Comment: Tenant account is not a local one. It is a Azure account which is synced to ServiceNow.

Comment: Then prefix the domain?

Comment: @Scepticalist Can you please let me know where to prefix in the above code? I'm not clear on that. Much appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to first enlighten *us* on how you define `$TenantAdmin` in this matter.

Comment: @iRon It's user account with global administrator rights in azure.

Comment: Yes, but how do you define it? Do you use e.g. `Get-Credential`? if yes, what do you enter for the username? `<domain>\<username>`?

Comment: @iRon $TenantAdmin = "{UserAccount}"
$TenantAdminCredential = '{Encrypted password}'

$TenantCredential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $TenantAdmin, (ConvertTo-SecureString -a -f (Unprotect-CmsMessage -IncludeContext –To "*svc.accountman@olive.com*" -Content $TenantAdminCredential))

Comment: (please, add the information to the question.) So did you try to set the domain name in the account, like:`$TenantAdmin = 'AzureDomain\username'` or just `$TenantAdmin = '.\username'`

Comment: @iRon I tried as you said above. The issue still persists.

Comment: @iRon I checked the credentials and it seems to be fine. Even I created new account and that doesn't work either.